# IPropertyStory doing SetValue without Commit

Tags: winapi, ipropertystorage

I'm following this blog to write the same code to change the `System.AppUserModel.ID` of a window: [The Old New Thing :: How do I prevent users from pinning my program to the taskbar?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/01/10170113.aspx)

He is doing:

```
hr = pps->SetValue(pkey, var);
PropVariantClear(&var);
```

He does not do a `pps->Commit()`, I'm getting confused because I have written the code, I do `SetValue` and I do `Commit` but my changes won't take.

How come he doesn't do `Commit`? Is he mistaken? Or is his a special case where you don't need `Commit`?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that window property stores aren't persistent, and so there's no need to explicitly commit changes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, the `var` was set to a propvariant which was not properly initailized. My InitFromString function was messing up it would forget to set the `var.vt`. I dont know why a succesful hr was being returned though.